# ClojureScript Reagent Parent component won't pass cursor to child component

Tags: javascript, html, web-component, clojurescript, reagent

I am trying to create a simple dynamic svg. One where the viewbox settings update with change in the window dimensions.

To do this I have a top level component defined as follows

```
(defn windowdim_comp
 []
 (with-let [wndcomp_state (atom {:text "Parent2Component"})
         resize_handler #(swap! wndcomp_state assoc
                         :height (.-innerHeight js/window)
                         :width (.-innerWidth js/window))
         mousemove_handler #(swap! wndcomp_state assoc
                                   :x (.-pageX %)
                                   :y (.-pageY %))
         _ (.addEventListener js/window "resize" resize_handler)
         _ (.addEventListener js/document "mousemove" mousemove_handler)
         _ (swap! wndcomp_state assoc :height (.-innerHeight js/window))
         _ (swap! wndcomp_state assoc :width (.-innerWidth js/window))]
[:div
 [:p "width : " (:width @wndcomp_state) " height : " (:height @wndcomp_state)]
 [:p "x : " (:x @wndcomp_state) " y : " (:y @wndcomp_state)]
 (svgrender (cursor wndcomp_state [:text :width :height]))
 ]
(finally
  (.removeEventListener js/window "resize" resize_handler)
  (.removeEventListener js/document "mousemove" mousemove_handler))))
```

This component then calls a child component called svgrender with a cursor taking just the :text :width & :height values... defined as follows:

```
(defn svgrender
 [parent_state]
  (with-let [svgstate (atom {:clicked false})
           mousedown_handler #(swap! svgstate assoc
                                     :clicked true)
           mouseup_handler #(swap! svgstate assoc
                                   :clicked false)]
    [:svg {:viewBox "0 0 500 500"
         :width 500
         :height 500
         :id "svgcontainer"
         :onMouseDown mousedown_handler
         :onMouseUp mouseup_handler}
      [:g {:id "layer1"}
       [:rect {:id "rect1"
            :width 500
            :height 500
            :x 0
            :y 0
            :style {:fill (if (:clicked @svgstate)
                            "#ff00ff"
                            "#00ffff")}}]
         [:text {:x 5
            :y 15
            :class "small"}
          (gstring/format "width : %s height : %s" (:width @parent_state) (:height @parent_state))]
         [:text {:x 5
            :y 35
            :class "small"}
          (gstring/format "Click status : %s" (:clicked @svgstate))]
         [:text {:x 5
            :y 55
            :class "small"}
          "Parent Text:  " (:text @parent_state)]]]
        (finally
          (.removeEventListener (.getElementById js/document "svgcontainer")
                          "onmousedown" mousedown_handler)
          (.removeEventListener (.getElementById js/document "svgcontainer")
                          "onmouseup" mouseup_handler))))
```

The the problem is no matter what I do, I can't get the values from the parent_state to display in the child node.... they just display as nulls
[image]

Please can someone help me? I don't know what I am doing wrong!!

**UPDATE:**
As per suggestion from Walton I've come up with a few variations

1. Parens call to component with full parent state passed

   (svgrender wndcomp_state)

Result : Fail

2. Parens call to component with cursor like in the original code

   (svgrender (cursor wndcomp_state [:text :width :height]))

Result : Fail

3. Parens call to component with track as per Walton's suggestion

   (svgrender (track #(select-keys @wndcomp_state [:text :width :height])))

Result : Pass!!

4. Square call to component with full parent state passed

   [svgrender wndcomp_state]

Result : Pass!!

5. Square call to component with cursor like in the original code

   [svgrender (cursor wndcomp_state [:text :width :height])]

Result : Fail

6. Square call to component with track as per Walton's suggestion

   [svgrender (track #(select-keys @wndcomp_state [:text :width :height]))]

Result : Pass!!

Now this is so bizzare.... no? While I accept Walton's answer, can anyone explain why this is the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[cursor](https://reagent-project.github.io/docs/master/reagent.core.html#var-cursor) behaves like [get-in](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/get-in), while the code above expects it to behave like [select-keys](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/select-keys). While you could make cursor behave like your want by passing in a function as the first argument (see the second example in it's documentation) you don't need to write the cursor, so your better off using [track](https://reagent-project.github.io/docs/master/reagent.core.html#var-track). Something like `(track #(select-keys @wndcomp_state [:text :width :height]))` (untested)

That said, in your example, even track is overkill, you really don't need a new reaction. You could just pass in the original atom to the child component and everything would would perfectly. The downside of doing this is that if your example is simplified and you have other properties that change more frequently than `:width` and `:height` you'd rerender the child necessarily every time those changed.

Even that problem can be solved without a new reaction however. Just pass in the plain map. So instead of `[svgrender (track #(select-keys @wndcomp_state [:text :width :height]))]` you simply have `[svgrender (select-keys @wndcomp_state [:text :width :height])]` (note: I'm also using square brackets instead of parens, see [here](https://cljdoc.org/d/reagent/reagent/1.0.0/doc/tutorials/using-square-brackets-instead-of-parentheses-)). Using this approach when `wndcomp_state` changes the `windowdim_comp` component will be re-rendered, which causes it to call the `svgrender` component with the text, width, and height from `wndcomp_state`. If these have changed, it's like calling a React component with new props, it'll be rerendered. If they haven't your calling `svgrender` with the same arguments it was originally rendered with. Reagent won't rerender it in that scenario (using the square brackets. With parens it'll always be rerendered).

Same effect, but less work for Reagent/React tracking dependencies.

Comment: Hi Walton. Thanks for the reply. For me calling svgrender with the entire wndcomp_state wasn't working with parens. When I changed it to square brackets, it works with entire wndcomp_state. It also works with track as per your suggestion. But ONLY with square brackets!! In both cases cursor fails!! This is bizzare. I'll repaste the code in my update. You've solved my issue so I'll accept your answer. However it'll be great to understand the why behind the phenomenon. I am a total newbie... so maybe I am just being silly.... :D

Comment: I wasn't paying enough attention when I said the parens should work. `with-let` creates a form-2 component see: https://github.com/reagent-project/reagent/blob/master/doc/CreatingReagentComponents.md. I was assuming a form 1 component, which because they return plain hiccup (plain vectors), instead of a function will work (kind of) when called with parens (as an actual function).

It's probably not a good SO question, but if you want a better idea of how Reagent rendering works, I'd suggest Clojurians slack: https://clojurians.slack.com/?redir=%2Fmessages.

Comment: The short version is parens `()` aren't rendering a component at all. They are simply calling a function, just like any other function call. Reagent knows nothing about it, doesn't even know a call happened. If that function happens to return valid hiccup, great, but it's no different than if the hiccup had just been inlined from the start. On the other hand when the first part of some hiccup `[]` is a function, Reagent tries to turn it into a component, following the rules I linked above. So Reagent renders it a component independent of it's parent.

Comment: In other words, form-1 components usually work with `()`, but it's by coincidence, not by design, and they sometimes won't respond to changes they way you expect, because they aren't actually independent components, but instead part of the component they were rendered in. You basically always want `[]`.

Comment: cool!! Thanks Walton. I'll check out your link and will keep this in mind for the future. Thanks again!!